# How to use the SFSafariViewController and use your own http proxy？

Tags: ios, proxy, uiwebview, google-oauth, sfsafariviewcontroller

in my app, I use uiwebview to load "account.google.com" and I use to nsprotocol integration to implement http proxy，but Now I must use SFSafariViewController to load google([no longer allow OAuth requests to Google in embedded browsers](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html)), still want to use http proxy. There are good people to help me solve this problem?

Comment: We have exact same problem. Have you find any solution?

Comment: Hi, does anybody find any solution to solve this?